# How do I return a string that will be populated with a variable from an asynchronous operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, ejs

I am wanting to produce a url template string similar to this `http://localhost:9090/api/${randomId}`, and implement this in a index.ejs file with the following HTML tag `<a href="urlTemplateString">Click Here To See User Profile</a>`.

I am using a Mongo database to retrieve this `randomId` using the following `Users.find({}).distinct("_id")`. Once I have got all user ids, I want a random id from the array. To achieve this I have used lodash `_.sample()`.

I am using JavaScript Promises to try and get my desired random id to be in a string. However, when I come to `res.render()` the result, all I seem to be getting is `http://localhost:9090/api/[object Promise]`.

So far, the code I have is as follows:

```
function getRandomUserId(req, res, next) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
   resolve(Users.find({}).distinct("_id"))
)
.then(allUserIds => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(_.sample(allUserIds)));
})
.then(randomId => {
  res.render("index.ejs", {
    link: `http://localhost:9090/api/${randomId}`
  });
 });
}
```

I am able to retrieve a random id and console log this random id, but I am unable to return this random id to the final url template string.

How can I perform this asynchronous operation to return a `randomId` to the url template string?

Comment: It returns undefined. If I `console.log(randomId)` I can see the random id, but I am unable to return it as part of the url string, without it saying `Promise { <pending> }`.

Comment: Run some tests to debug the code. Eg. Find out which of the two promises remains pending; inject a string value and see if it behaves differently etc etc.

Comment: is `Users.find({}).distinct("_id")` synchronous ? is `_.sample(allUserIds)` synchronous ?

Comment: `Users.find({}).distinct("_id")` is asynchronous and `_.sample(allUserIds)` should be synchronous once all random ids have been returned to the first `then` block.

Comment: If `Users.find({}).distinct("_id")` is asynchronous (and returns Promise), that's the problem. `getRandomUserId()` should simply `return Users.find({}).distinct("_id")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getRandomUserId(req, res, next)
{
    return Users.find({}).distinct("_id").exec() // assuming mongoose
    .then((allUserIds) => 
    {
        res.render
        (
            "index.ejs", 
            {
                link: `http://localhost:9090/api/${_.sample(allUserIds)}`
            }
        );
    });
}
```